# html5 videojs script not working with modal popup

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

In my html file, I have integrated the bootstrap modal pop.

Here i list more than 10 videos with owl carousel. By clicking each video thumb, the corresponding video will be played.

This is my player code:

```
<div id="mediaspace2968631" class="videoplayer  player vc_col-sm-9 left-video" style="margin-top:0px;">
```

On each video thumb click the fuction called as `change_video_cat(vvideo,vimg,id,n)`

```
    function change_video_cat(vvideo,vimg,id,n) {
    frmid = 'item_'+id;

    $(".item").removeClass('curactive');
    $("#"+frmid).addClass('curactive');


    myPlayer =   videojs('vid3', {
    'techOrder': ['youtube', 'html5'], "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto","poster": vimg
    }).ready(function() {
        var player = this;
        player.src({ src: vvideo, type: 'video/youtube' });
    });

}
```

If I close the modal popup, and open it again, at that time the following error occured as

`VIDEOJS: WARN: Player "vid3" is already initialised. Options will not be applied.`

Please help me to fix this. The video played smoothly and owl carousel worked fine at the first time of modal open. If I close the modal popup, and open it again, the page not working and video not displayed. carousel corrupted.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this issue here:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/removing-players.md

```js
var oldPlayer = document.getElementById('my-player');
videojs(oldPlayer).dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method. It will work.

```js
try {
  if (videojs("video-id")) {
    videojs("vide-id").dispose();
  }
} catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the warning states the player with id `vid` already exists when you create it the second time around.

If you are re-showing the same div and player the second time around, just loading the new video into the existing player may work for you. Otherwise use unique ids in each modal, or dispose of the player before closing the modal with `myPlayer.dispose()`.